# How to bind tqdm progressbar with searching files in python

Tags: python, tqdm

I wrote a function which search files with tqdm progressbar. But how to write code to avoid this effect while listing files (image):
[image]
I want just single progressbar that loads at the same time listing files.

```
        counter = 0
            filepath = "." 
            ext = ".txt" # for example
            for fil in os.listdir(filepath):
                if fil.endswith(ext):
                    print(fil)
                    counter+=1
                    sleep(0.01)
                for i in tqdm(range(counter)):
                    i+=1
            print("\nNumber of found elements: "+str(counter))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tqdm while iterating:

```
        filepath = "." 
        ext = ".txt" # for example
        for fil in tqdm(os.listdir(filepath)):
            if fil.endswith(ext):
                print(fil)
                counter+=1
                sleep(0.01)
        print("\nNumber of found elements: "+str(counter))
```